# Is it possible to disable the UIModalPresentationFormSheet animation?

Tags: ios, ipad, animation, uiviewcontroller

On iPad, when a viewcontroller is shown using `UIModalPresentationFormSheet` and and the keyboard shows up, the system automatically move this viewcontroller up of about 55 px. This happens only in landscape.

Unfortunately this animation brake our way to deal with keyboard.
Does someone know how to disable it?

Comment: You're probably dealing with the keyboard wrong :) You can't change the default presentation, you'd have to write your own. But it's probably easier just to handle the keyboard properly - how are you doing that at the moment?

Comment: I can imagine that some other approach will be not bothered by this animation. In my case I get the keyboard frame and the current view height.
    `current_heigh - keyboard_origin_y` give me the amount of pixel that I have to move my view up. Unfortunately the height of the view is animated by iOS and this give me a wrong result.